# crystal report formula fields not adjust

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I use crystal report formula fields like:

[image]

and i set indentation to 0:

[image]

but when i get PDF file in client i receive this:

[image]

crystal report set indentation(margin) from left automatically, also i set indentation Equuleus 0
Thanks!

Comment: Couldnt understand what is wrong in pdf output

Comment: Can you add a sample pic of expected output?

Comment: Figure 3 is output and updated: Error: "This margin add automatically"